# Definitions - Print Quotient and Remainder - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am asked to write a function called longDivision() that takes two integers as arguments and prints a well-labeled output of the quotient and remainder of the first argument divided by the second.

This is my attempt at getting the quotient but I keep getting the error: 'TypeError: longDivision() missing 1 required positional argument: 'second'

Code:

```
first = float(input("Enter a number: "))
second = float(input("Enter a number: "))
def longDivision(first, second):
    divideNum = first//second
    remainNum = first%second
    return divideNum
print(longDivision("The quotient is: "))
```

I don't know how I would get it to print the remainder either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
first = float(input("Enter a number: "))
second = float(input("Enter a number: "))

def longDivision(num1, num2): # parameters can have different names than actual variables
    divideNum = num1 // num2
    remainNum = num1 % num2
    return divideNum, remainNum   # return both quotient and remainder

quo, rem = longDivision(first, second)  # Pass the correct parameters

print("The quotient is: ", quo) 
print("The remainder is: ", rem)
```

**What's wrong with your code**

- `return divideNum`  You are only returning quotient. You need to return both quotient and remainder
- `longDivision("The quotient is: ")`  You are passing as string as a parameter while your function takes 2 float parameters